# (PYTHON, TKINTER) How can I get radiobuttons to delete with my canvases? (School Project Combat Game)

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, radio-button, ttk

I am trying to figure out how to delete radiobuttons along with my canvas when it switches to the next one.

my code:

(P.S., I am trying to make it so that after the user's turn ends, another canvas with the same properties (but with a fresh set of radiobuttons) opens up, allowing the user to play their next turn. Open to any suggestions/improvements!)

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

def game_canvas():
    global c, var
    c.destroy()
    c = Canvas(root, height = 720, width = 1280, bg = 'black')
    c.pack()

    #creates the background of the scene
    c.create_image(0, 0, image = arena, anchor = NW)

    #adds the user and griffin's images
    c.create_image(300, 95, image = user_geralt_image2, anchor = NW)
    c.create_image(875, 300, image = griffin_image)

    #creates and places the button to go to the next canva
    confirm_button = Button(c, text = 'Comfirm', command = action, font = 'Calibri 16', borderwidth = 5)
    create_confirm_button = c.create_window(1156, 685, window = confirm_button)

    #creates and places the button to quit the game
    quit_button = Button(c, text = 'Quit', command = exit_confirmation, font = 'Calibri 16', borderwidth = 5)
    create_quit_button = c.create_window(1241, 685, window = quit_button)

    var = IntVar()
    r1 = Radiobutton(root, text = 'Attack', font = 'Calibri 16', variable = var, value = 1)
    r1.pack(anchor = W)

    r2 = Radiobutton(root, text = 'Parry', font = 'Calibri 16', variable = var, value = 2)
    r2.pack(anchor = W)

    r3 = Radiobutton(root, text = 'Dodge', font = 'Calibri 16', variable = var, value = 3)
    r3.pack(anchor = W)

root.mainloop()
```

I've done a few google searches to find a way to attach the radioheads to the Canvas, but to no avail.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please read and try to following the instructions here: [mcve]. You've posted to much code to be generally useful for a stackoverflow question.

Comment: sorry! i'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two simple solutions, based on the same principle.

First, you can make the radiobuttons a child of the canvas. When you delete the canvas, all children will automatically be deleted.

Since you didn't do that, I'm guessing you want the radiobuttons to be outside of the canvas. In that case, the simplest thing is to make both the radio buttons and the canvas a frame. When you delete the frame, all of the widgets will be destroyed too.

Comment: sorry for  the late reply, how would I go about making the canvas the parent for the radiobuttons?

Comment: @soggothememe: replace `root` with `c` in statements like `Radiobutton(root, ...)`.